# textbox inside the div does not react for any margin or padding changes

Tags: html, css, textbox, position, hex

here's the code:

[...]

```
<style>
  .hex {
    float: left;
    background-color: transparent;}

    .top, .bottom {
    width: 0;
    border-left: 2.2em solid transparent;
    border-right: 2.2em solid transparent;}

   .bottom{border-top: 1.25em solid #6C6;}

   .top{border-bottom: 1.25em solid #6C6;}


   .middle{
    width: 1.46em;
    height: 0.8em;
    background: #6C6;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3em;
    line-height: 1em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid red;}

   .hex .middle input{
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    background: transparent;
    border: 1px solid;
    width:5em;}

  </style>
```

[...]

```
<body>
  <div class="hex"> 
     <div class="top"></div>
     <div class="middle">
       <input type="text" class="playerName" id="name1" maxlength="7" value="what" disabled/>
     </div>
     <div class="bottom"></div> 
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

full example - http://jsbin.com/iqanoh/1

could someone please explain me, why can't I control position of textbox(black) inside the div(red). It does not react for any: margin or padding changes. Generally I'd like to center (horizontally and vertically), but it's always on bottom even a little bit under.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `display: block` to the `input` to make `margin` take effect. By default `input` has `display: inline` and it wont work with margin.

Answer (score 0):

there is a problem in the `.middle` div

```
.middle {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #66CC66;
    border: 1px solid red;
    font-size: 3em;
    height: 0.8em;
    line-height: 1em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 1.46em;
}
```

remove **`font-size`**, **`line-height`** and **`width`** from it. 
hope this will solve your issue.